# AsyncTask, Fragments, Views, and Backstacks

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I've been using this pattern for a bit. Here is a very contrived example of an AsyncTask + progress indicator:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    WeakReference<MyFragment> weakFragment = new WeakReference<MyFragment>(MyFragment.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Fragment fragment = weakFragment.get();
        if(fragment != null) fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.progress).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);        
    }

    @Override
    protected Document doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Fragment fragment = weakFragment.get();
        if(fragment == null) return null;

        // Do something ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute() {                
        Fragment fragment = weakFragment.get();
        if(fragment != null) fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.progress).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}.execute();
```

It works okay with orientation changes, but I've noticed the fragment being non-null and fragment.getView() being null when I pop the fragment off the backstack. That obviously causes this to crash. What approach are you folks using? I can't seem to find a perfect solution online. Important note, this is in a fragment and I call `setRetainInstance(true);` on that fragment in its onActivityCreated(...).

Comment: Use a messaging bus or local broadcast receiver.

Comment: For a progress bar? :| That's a bit much don't you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AsyncTask` is an asynchronous task which means you usually do not know when it is completed and when it calls `onPostExecute()`. I think your problem is here. When you rotate your device your asynctask has not finished yet and your fragment view is destroyed and recreates again very quickly while still asynctask is on the worker thread and when it has done its job your fragment has a view and `getView`'s return value is not `null`. But if the rotation time takes much you will get `null` because the `AsyncTask` has finished but your fragment does not have any view. Now this scenario is exactly happens to your backstack When you push your fragment on to the backstack its view is destroyed([look at the picture](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating)) but the fragment itself is not (the fragment returns to the layout from backstack). Now your `AsyncTask` finishes and call your `fragment` `getView` method and it dose not have any `view` so you will get `NPE`.

My solution:

First you should use `WeakReference<ProgressBar>` instead of `WeakReference<MyFragment>` and in `onPostExecute()` check whether it is null or not, if it is null do nothing because the default value is invisible if it is not null call `setVisibility(View.GONE)`.

Update:

> the fragment is alive but the view has been dealloc'd. Is this
>   possible?

Yes, just look at the figure2 from link. When fragment is active (green box) `the fragment added to back stack` fragment goes to `onPause`, `onStop` **onDestroyView**. Then when the fragment pops up from back stack it goes right to `onCreateView` the arrow link with this text:`the fragment returns to the layout from backstack`.

In order to confirm my answer you can create an `AsyncTask` and call `SystemClock.sleep(30000)` inside your `doInbackground`. Now you can push your fragment in to the backstack and pops it up from backstack with no exception because the asynctask has not finished and when it will call `onPostExecute()` your fragment already has a view.

Another good thing you can see is [setRetainInstance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29)

> This can only be used with fragments not in the back stack.

So when you push your fragment into back stack it **may** destroy completely and you **may** get new fragment reference when it pops up. But when you use `setRetainInstance(true);` for configuration changes your fragment **is retained across Activity re-creation** which means it is the **same** fragment and `onCreate` is not called. And this is a very very important thing because if you start your `AsyncTask` at the `onCreate` method, when you push your fragment into the back stack and pop it up you **may** have a new fragment and this means `onCreate` method runs and another `AsyncTask` is fired. That means you do not have any control over the number of calling `AsyncTask`s so watch out for 
memory leaks!

Comment: Right, I see where you are coming from. This is why I am using the weak reference to the fragment in the first place. The behaviour I *think* I'm running into is that the fragment is alive but the view has been dealloc'd. Is this possible? Maybe some more clarification on this would help.

Comment: Thanks for your help @mmlooloo. This clears things up, but I'm still not sure as to the best practices in handling fragment and fragment.getView() in an async task.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean but your question is not very complicated, simply in some situations you have a fragment and that fragment dose not have any view, so calling getView will result in NPE.

Comment: If I need to access the fragment's view, now I need to check if the fragment is alive (as I should be holding a weak reference), check if its getView() is alive, and probably all its data members too cause they could be null'd. Is this correct? It just seems over the top for something quite small.

Comment: yes it is, but all I want to tell you is: There are some situations that your fragment is alive but dose not have any view. so simply calling getView result in NPE. In order to solve that store your widget in a weak Reference instead of fragment. and also you do not need any sharedpreferences i updated my solution section of my answer if you noticed.